# Lookup route for URL in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Does Ember expose an API I can use to manually look up a route (as a dot separated path) from a URL?

For example:

```
Ember.routeForURL('/foo/bar')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API for that as far as I know. What you can do is use router's recognizer.

```
let owner = Ember.getOwner(this);
let router = owner.lookup('router:main');
let handlers = router.router.recognizer.recognize('/foo/bar')
```

"handlers" will contain an array of objects where handler property will be something like this ["application", "foo", "foo.bar"]

And then you can probably use the last handler to do

```
owner.lookup('route:' + lastHandler)
```

Comment: In newer ember versions you should use: `router._routerMicrolib.recognizer.recognize('/foo/bar')`